# Create a git server side hook for sanity check of configuration file

Tags: bash, git, githooks, bitbucket-server

I would like to create a server side git hook to perform a sanity check on a configuration file in a repository.

Based on my research I came across "pre-receive" hooks ( a hook that gets triggered upon push ).

I setup my testing atlassian bitbucket server and create a new repository to which I navigated into the pre-receive hook directory in which scripts should reside.

Created a test script that rejects any push on master with an error print. Everything works fine so far.

Now, to my sanity check hook.
I came up with the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONFIGFILE = "full-path-to-config-file"
EXPECTED_CONF_MASTER = "configEntry1=expectedValue1"
EXPECTED_CONF_TEST = "configEntry2=expectedValue2"

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    echo "$refname : $oldrev --> $newrev"
    current_branch=$refname
    short_current_branch="$(echo $current_branch | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')"

    newFiles=$(git diff --stat --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${oldrev} ${newrev})

    if [[ "$short_current_branch" = "test" ]]; then

        echo $newFiles | grep $CONFIGFILE >/dev/null || exit 0 #CONFIGFILE has not been modified
        git cat-file --textconv "${newrev}:$CONFIGFILE" | grep "$EXPECTED_CONF_TEST" || echo "invalid config" && exit 1

    elif [[ "$short_current_branch" = "master" ]]; then

        echo $newFiles | grep $CONFIGFILE >/dev/null || exit 0 #CONFIGFILE has not been modified
        git cat-file --textconv "${newrev}:$CONFIGFILE" | grep "$EXPECTED_CONF_MASTER" || echo "invalid config" && exit 1

    fi

done
```

However, I keep getting this error upon push. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
Username for 'http://localhost:7990': seif
Password for 'http://seif@localhost:7990': 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 386 bytes | 386.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: refs/heads/test : 1820f938babb12800d7d7726859bb86c03edb12a --> 28a1e8113d9ceebc41c6dd2d29a1ec2ebf626510
remote: 
remote: fatal: Invalid revision range 1820f938babb12800d7d7726859bb86c03edb12a..28a1e8113d9ceebc41c6dd2d29a1ec2ebf626510
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for test:
remote:   http://localhost:7990/projects/myproj1/repos/bamboo-specs/pull-requests?create&sourceBranch=refs/heads/test
remote: 
To http://localhost:7990/scm/myproj1/bamboo-specs.git
   1820f93..28a1e81  test -> test
```

Comment: I see `echo "$refname : $oldrev ~ $newrev"`. But then, in the output, I see `remote: refs/heads/test : 1820f938babb12800d7d7726859bb86c03edb12a --> 28a1e8113d9ceebc41c6dd2d29a1ec2ebf626510`. No tilde, and an arrow instead. The remote is running a *different script*.

Comment: @torek Apologies, I tweaked the script when I extracted the log. I just edited to match. I am afraid it is the same script.

Comment: OK, but now the line `echo "Current branch: $short_current_branch"` isn't coming out. We should see `remote: Current branch: test`.

Comment: It sounds like you want CI/CD. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/integrated-ci-cd-1032257989.html

Comment: @torek Sorry again for the inconsistency between the script and the logs. I have tweaked the code locally prior to snapshotting the log.

Comment: The `fatal` message comes from using `$oldrev..$newrev` somewhere, perhaps in a shallow clone. The code you posted doesn't use that expression anywhere, but given that the code you posted and the output you posted don't match, I don't trust anything about the question at this point. :-) I know these things happen during debugging, but something has gone wrong, and I can't see what.

Comment: @KamilCuk I a afraid this sanity check needs to be executed prior to push, in other way to prevent a push on the repository in the first place. If you're wondering why, this is a bamboo-specs repository, basically any pushes on this repository would update our bamboo plans ( that is CI/CD), this sanity check is to prevent updating for example the project name to a the production one for  Bamboo plans in the test branch (that is test environment) and vice versa.
Assuming, the check can be done post push, creating CI/CD to verify the config sanity of CI/CD is an endless loop.

Comment: At this point my best guess is that you have this pre-receive hook working fine, and it did its job and exited zero, and then some *other* hook (probably a post-receive one) is producing the error. That fits with the fact that the push appears to have worked.

Comment: @torek  Not really, more tests have revealed some things to me.
If a new commit updates the file with a config value different than the expected one and I push it. It will bypass the test, because simply this line
newFiles=$(git diff --stat --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${oldrev} ${newrev})
exits with 0 even if it fails.
For some reason in the server side hook the newrev is not accessible by git diff command at least not before the push is successfull
I can confirm this, because  when I try to hard reset to the commit introducing the false config, the hook works because newrev is known.

Comment: Well, by *working* and *did its job* I mean it exited zero. If it doesn't do what you *want*, that's another problem. But the complaint (`fatal:. ...`) is not coming from the pre-receive hook: it's from some *other* hook.

Comment: BTW never use `git diff` in a hook: it's a "porcelain" (or user-facing) command and you want to use *plumbing* (command-facing) commands as much as possible. Use `git diff-tree`, `git diff-files`, or `git diff-index` depending on which one you mean, and here that would be `git diff-tree`. Use `--exit-code` and trim the diff using pathspecs, not grep.

Comment: When it comes to *testing a pre-receive script* you should just run it with input redirected to a file that contains "interesting" hash IDs and ref names, in a clone you've set up with commits that contain each of the conditions you wish to test. You can write the input file based on the commit hash IDs and run the script and observe its workings. You do all of this on some random Linux/Unix box (or a VM or whatever) and when it's all ready, then you install it on the real server.

Comment: @torek Found the issue, the incoming revision is not yet residing in the objects.
incoming commit blobs are stored under objects/incoming-<hash> , one has to set 
export GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=$(find . -type d -name 'incoming-*' | xargs realpath) to it.

Comment: Incoming objects are indeed stored in a quarantine area, but *you do not have to set any environment variables* because Git has already set them. What exactly are you doing here? (You must be clearing out environment variables, or using remote execution, or something, so that the environment is not being passed on correctly.)